# How can I replace the effects of the old trigger with a new trigger?

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have a Trigger below that inserts and replaces the first name and last name each time somebody tries to enter a new insert to the name and last name. The code is below. Now I want to create a new trigger that drops this trigger below and by each update inserts another new name in front of the first and last name. Please let me know what I should do to write my new trigger.For example the 'pirat' should be replaced with 'lawyer' and 'wild cat' with bully cat in the new trigger .

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trgInsertPirat ON Mitarbeiter
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @m_nr INT,
@m_vorname CHAR (50),
@m_name CHAR (50),
@abt_nr CHAR (4),
@abt_nr_p CHAR (4)

SET @m_nr = (SELECT m_nr FROM inserted)--id
SET @m_vorname = ('Pirat ' + (SELECT m_vorname FROM inserted))--first name
SET @m_name = ('wild cat ' + (SELECT m_name FROM inserted))--last name
SET @abt_nr = (SELECT abt_nr FROM inserted)--department number
SET @abt_nr_p = (right((SELECT abt_nr FROM inserted), 3))


INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter (m_nr, m_vorname, m_name, abt_nr)
VALUES (@m_nr, @m_vorname, @m_name, @abt_nr)

INSERT INTO Pirat (pirat_id, p_name, gang_id)
VALUES (@m_nr, @m_name, @abt_nr_p)
```

Comment: Your question is far from clear, however see this [recommended reading](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) on triggers.

Comment: in this trigger,each time i enter a new value for the first and last name the words pirat and wild cat are added to the names.. but now i want to make a new trigger that by updates changes the  pirat to lawyer and wild cat to bully cat

Comment: Other than reading the link in the previous comment (you'll discover your trigger doesn't work the way you think) have you considered if a trigger is the right solution, perhaps a *view* or *computed columns* would be a better approach.

Comment: Also it's unlikley names are all exactly 50 characters in length, have you maybe considered a *var*ying*char*acter type?

Comment: what data type is varying? I must use a trigger .I am learning about triggers

Comment: I would disregard whatever learning resources you have been following, no good tutorial on t-sql triggers will be advocating the use of local variables like you are doing.